# Python alternative for calculating pairwise distance between two sets of 2d points

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance

In Matlab there exists the `pdist2` command. Given the matrix `mx2` and the matrix `nx2`, each row of matrices represents a `2d` point. Now I want to create a `mxn` matrix such that `(i,j)` element represents the distance from `i`th point of `mx2` matrix to `j`th point of `nx2` matrix. I simply call the command `pdist2(M,N)`.

I am looking for an alternative to this in python. I can of course write 2 for loops but since I am working with 2 numpy arrays, using for loops is not always the best choice. Is there an optimized command for this in the python universe? Basically I am asking for python alternative to MATLAB's `pdist2`.

Comment: [`scipy pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)?

Comment: it calculates pairwise distances between points in the same matrix.

Comment: Sorry, it's been awhile.  [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) should do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) scipy function. It will calculate the pair-wise distances (euclidean by default) between two sets of n-dimensional matrices.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2)
Y = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2)

cdist(X, Y)
```

> ```
> [[  0.           2.82842712   5.65685425   8.48528137  11.3137085 ]
>  [  2.82842712   0.           2.82842712   5.65685425   8.48528137]
>  [  5.65685425   2.82842712   0.           2.82842712   5.65685425]
>  [  8.48528137   5.65685425   2.82842712   0.           2.82842712]
>  [ 11.3137085    8.48528137   5.65685425   2.82842712   0.        ]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `pairwise_distances` method of the `scikit-learn` package.

`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X, Y=None, metric='euclidean', n_jobs=1, **kwds)`

More information in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is not too big, this should do without using other libs. If the matrix is big, this method will be a bit slow and memory intensive.

```
mx2 = np.random.randint(1,9,5)    
nx2 = np.random.randint(1,9,3)    
mx2
Out[308]: array([2, 3, 4, 8, 7])    
nx2
Out[309]: array([3, 2, 2])    
mx2[:,None]-nx2
Out[310]: 
array([[-1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  6],
       [ 4,  5,  5]])
```