# How make a vectorized approach for calculating pair-wise Manhattan/L1 distance between multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have two arrays of size (4000, 3). What I'd like to do in a vectorized fashion is to calculate the L1/Manhattan distance from each vector of the first array to every vector in the second array, so that I'd end up with a (4000, 4000) array.

My current approach is based on splitting up the (4000, 3) into 3 separate arrays of (4000, 1) and doing broadcasting (similar to here: [Python alternative for calculating pairwise distance between two sets of 2d points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650931/python-alternative-for-calculating-pairwise-distance-between-two-sets-of-2d-poin)).

However, this approach doesn't really work if I have initial matrices that are different in size, for example, (4000, 4) or (4000, 5). Then my code would break, because it's assuming there are 3 channels.

Therefore, I'd appreciate any help on creating a generalized vectorized approach that can calculate pairwise L1 distances!

Comment: Think cdist should work regardless of number of channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the whole thing using broadcasting (if I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly). First compute the pairwise differences of the vectors (result is shape `N,N,k`), then compute the sum of the absolute values of each of these vectors.

```
N = 4000
k = 4

X = np.random.rand(N,k)
Y = np.random.rand(N,k)

Z = np.sum(np.abs(X[:,None]-Y[:]),axis=-1)
```